# Why is the discrete field scaled by the square root of the lattice constant when continuum limit is taken?

Tags: field-theory

In the book *Condense Matter Field Theory* by Altland, at page 5, it is given that

$$\left.\phi_{I} \rightarrow a^{1 / 2} \phi(x)\right|_{x=I a}, \quad \phi_{I+1}-\left.\phi_{I} \rightarrow a^{3 / 2} \partial_{x} \phi(x)\right|_{x=I a}, \quad \sum_{I=1}^{N} \rightarrow \frac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{L} d x$$

However, what is the reason for $ a^{1 / 2}$ scaling of $\phi$ and $a^{3 / 2}$ scaling of the derivative?